# How do I download a file or photo that was sent to my telegram bot using telegraf module?

Tags: node.js, telegraf

I am using node.js [telegraf](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf) module to create a telegram bot.

I am using the code below.

```
var picture = (context)ctx.message.photo[0].file_id; 
var photo = `https://api.telegram.org/bot1234-ABCD/getFile?file_id=${picture}`;
console.log(photo.file_path);
```

Comment: Not a [mcve], f.ex what is `ctx`? What error message do you get?

Comment: @StefanBecker Since it's a new user it might be worth to adress him the subtle way: 
Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 7):

You can use axios to store the images. Assuming you have the file id as `fileId` and the context as `ctx`. I am storing the image at the path `${config.basePath}/public/images/profiles/${ctx.update.message.from.id}.jpg`

```
ctx.telegram.getFileLink(fileId).then(url => {    
    axios({url, responseType: 'stream'}).then(response => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${config.basePath}/public/images/profiles/${ctx.update.message.from.id}.jpg`))
                        .on('finish', () => /* File is saved. */)
                        .on('error', e => /* An error has occured */)
                });
            })
})
```

**How do I get the file id of the image sent for the bot**

```
bot.on('message', ctx => {
    const files = ctx.update.message.photo;
    // telegram stores the photos for different sizes
    // here is a sample files result
    // [ { file_id:
    //   'AgADBAADgbAxG768CFDXChKUnJnzU5jjLBsABAEAAwIAA20AA_PFBwABFgQ',
    //   file_size: 29997,
    //   width: 320,
    //   height: 297 },
    //   { file_id:
    //   'AgADBAADgbAxG768CFDXChKUnJnzU5jjLBsABAEAAwIAA3gAA_HFBwABFgQ',
    //   file_size: 80278,
    //   width: 580,
    //   height: 538 } ]
    //   })

    // I am getting the bigger image
    fileId = files[1].file_id
    // Proceed downloading
});
```

Don't forget to install axios as `npm install axios --save` and require it as `const axios = require('axios')`

**N.B.** Don't publish the file links publicly as it exposes your bot token.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ npm install needle
```

```js
var needle = require('needle');

...

needle.get(`https://api.telegram.org/bot1234:ABCD/getFile?file_id=${picture}`, function(error, response) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    console.log(response.body.result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download the highest quality photo you can use this command for the high quality file id
let fileId = ctx.message.photo.pop().file_id;

Answer (score 0):

When the user sends an image, the content of `ctx.message` is as follows:

```
{
    message_id: 111,
    from: {...},
    ...
    photo: [
      {
        file_id: 'XXXX',
        file_unique_id: 'YYYY',
        file_size: 1234,
        width: 43,
        height: 90
      },
       ...
      {
        file_id: 'XXXX',
        file_unique_id: 'YYYY',
        file_size: 64202,
        width: 606,
        height: 1280
      }
    ]
}
```

> The last element of `photo` array is the **highest resolution**

```
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");
const { message } = require("telegraf/filters");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");


bot.on(message("photo"), async (ctx) => {
    let imageId = ctx.message.photo.pop().file_id;

    ctx.telegram.getFileLink(imageId).then((link) => {
        https.get(link, (response) =>
            response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`path/img/${imageId}.jpeg`))
        );
    });
});
```

> Use `pop()` to get the last element, What we need from this element is `file_id`